# assembly container for Android MediaCodec

Tags: android, video, media, mime, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Is there anything that does the **opposite** of a MediaExtractor on android?
Take one or multiple streams from MediaCodecs (e.g. 1 video and 1 audio)
and package them in a container format for streaming or writing to files?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is no.
Mostly because of the underlying API is designed for video streaming and not for video compression.
Writing encoder's output to file you'll get raw h264 file. Which can be played using mplayer or ffplay for example.
Also ffmpeg can be used to mux this raw file into some container. But first of all you need to  build ffmpeg for android.

Comment: Actually it's NOT designed for video streaming since not a single streaming-capable container is supported.  Even if you could get the output of the encoders directly (you can't in Android <4 and their output is undocumented in 4.x) you would still need a lot of values that go into the headers of the container and are not part of the raw h264-stream.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, "not for writing to container" is more correct.
Maybe encoder's output is undocumented, but it is a raw h264 for now.
mplayer displays such video without problems.